# Code coverage tool for netbeans 7 module development

Tags: java, code-coverage, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am looking for a code coverage plugin for netbeans that supports JDK 7, Netbeans 7.4 and Module development. The closest one is TikiOne JaCoCoverage but it does not support module development.

Is there any plugin for that combination? How can i find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you may need to change or add some segment of the plugin sections in the POM.xml. It seems like this was the way when creating maven projects.

Comment: I am not talking about Maven based module. You did not understand the question, i think

Comment: For modular system you can build it with ant, try this tutorial https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-test.html

Comment: Thanks but, cobertura based coverage is based on Java 6. I am talking about unit test coverage of Java 7 and Netbeans 7 based module project. But anyway thanks for the answers

Comment: tikione is for apps and maven based projects and the only code coverage plugin available for nb 7. Maybe you should try JaCoCoverage in nb 6 versions. Your welcome and good luck ..